# Customize color prompt in tcsh with conditional expression

Tags: linux, prompt, csh, tcsh

I would like to customize my prompt in tcsh as follows:

- Print username (cyan)
- Print current path (yellow)
- Print "git" (in green) if the current folder is a git folder, else print "no_git" (in red)

I tried in this way and for the first 2 points it works as expected, but I'm not able to have the last point work with the conditional color, since the terminal gives me error "Missing ]."

```
set red='%{\033[0;31m%}'
set green="%{\033[0;32m%}"
set yellow="%{\033[0;93m%}"
set cyan="%{\033[0;36m%}"
set end="%{\033[0m%}"
alias precmd 'set git_folder=`sh -c "if git branch > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo '${green}git'; else echo '${red}no_git'; fi"`; \\
              set prompt = "${cyan}%B%n%b${end} ${yellow}%/${end} ${git_folder} ${end} > "'
```

I tried also with different types of quotes but then other errors occurred.
Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thanks!!

Comment: You can get some semblance of debugging by changing your "she-bang" line to `#!/bin/csh -vx` at the top of your script, or you can launch your script from cmdline like `csh -vx ./myScript`. You'll see the line of code (or enclosing loop structure) exactly as in your ile, and then it will also display each line as it is executed, with variable substitutions in place you you can see what are the actual value of variables being used. Don't have time to try an debug your issue. Good luck.